# why paramiko ssh can't output the print info in realtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh

I use python3 ssh, now I can login remote device, and execute my remote C program, but the program print info can't display on local pc in realtime. If my C program use `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` to set non-buffering, my PC can get realtime info; I want to know if the C program don't set non-buffering, how can I get the remote realtime info on local PC.

Here is my code:

```
def get_ssh_log(hostip, login_name, pw, privaete_key, cmd):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(hostname='%s' % hostip, port=22, username='%s' % login_name, password='%s' % pw,key_filename='%s' % privaete_key)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("%s" % cmd, bufsize=1)
    for line in iter(stdout.readline, ""):
        print(line)
    ssh.close()
```

Comment: You know `"%s" % cmd` is just `cmd` right?

Comment: I guess the comment by @JohnZwinck also applies to all other uses of the `%` operator in this function.

Comment: @JohnZwinck yes,I know "%s" % cmd is just cmd;

Answer (score 0):

You can run any program under the wrapper `unbuffer` from the `expect` package.  In your case:

```
ssh.exec_command("unbuffer %s" % cmd)
```

Of course this assumes `unbuffer` is installed on the target machine.

Ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Comment: The remote device is an embed device which runs openwrt os, it's not convenient to install any package on it. If there is other way in python3 in local PC which can get the output in realtime .Thanks.

Comment: @simon: then you can implement the unbuffer program  yourself, perhaps in Python, and use SFTP to copy it to the target before execution.  Source code for such a program is here: http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/pty/unbuffer.c.html